# Run multi line script in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am having difficulty with my pipeline I'm trying to configured, based off of this document - [link](https://bridgecrew.io/blog/automate-infrastructure-tagging-with-yor-and-gitlab-ci/?utm_campaign=Monthly%20Newsletter&utm_medium=email&_hsmi=144058907&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-9h6FCtNDxV403VtYLmK81LyfDCuOouielmCd5QSV_7KFZuNBmL-SITscrGZc_Kaur-sNxaj0PQ0Wly2wCybwP_XrAmsQp6F1hzdZiXWioEukCoHVY&utm_content=144058905&utm_source=hs_email)

I am trying to integrate the example pipeline code into my current one, I have got this far:

```
default:
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:light
    entrypoint:
      - /usr/bin/env
      - "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

stages:
  - validate
  - yor


validate:
  stage: validate
  before_script:
    - rm -rf .terraform
    - terraform --version
    - terraform init
    - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
  script:
    - terraform validate -json
  only:
    - merge_requests    

run-yor:
  stage: yor
  image: ruby:2.5
  script:
    - git checkout ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
    - export YOR_VERSION=0.1.62
    - wget -q -O - https://github.com/bridgecrewio/yor/releases/download/${YOR_VERSION}/yor-${YOR_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar -xvz -C /tmp
    - /tmp/yor tag -d .
  after_script:
    - |
      cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR
      git status
      lines=$(git status -s | wc -l)
      if [ $lines -gt 0 ];then
        echo "committing"
        git config --global user.name "$AUTO_COMMITTER_NAME"
        git config --global user.email "$AUTO_COMMITTER_EMAIL"
        echo ".yor_plugins" >> .gitignore
        git add .
        git commit -m "YOR: Auto add/update yor.io tags."
        git push -o ci.skip "https://${GITLAB_USER_NAME}:${GIT_PUSH_TOKEN}@${CI_REPOSITORY_URL#*@}"
      else
        echo "no updated resources, nothing to commit."
      fi
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

However, when running I receive this error in the output:

```
Running after_script
00:01
Running after script...
$ cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR # collapsed multi-line command
HEAD detached at c839d93
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   cloudformation.tf
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
committing
*** Please tell me who you are.
Run
  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
fatal: empty ident name (for <>) not allowed
```

It seems like it is not parsing the multi line script correctly and I cannot figure out how exactly to get this working. I also see in the original script on the linked page, the script is called differently, I'll be honest I don't fully understand how they are calling the script.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Not sure if the problem is with multiline. By the way, take a look at this post to understand yaml + multilines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines/21699210#21699210

Comment: Why not just putting all that stuff into a script file and call this from `after_script`?

Comment: Also, did you actually define any value for AUTO_COMMITTER_NAME and AUTO_COMMITTER_EMAIL?

Comment: @slauth yes the variables are set in the repos settings.
I will try setting this script in a separate script and call it that way instead, I just followed the instructions in the link I shared.
I'm starting to think the issue is not the multi line script but it is something else potentially the commit it's trying to check out.

Answer (score 8):

```
deploy:native-application:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - |
      mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package -DskipTests \
      -Pnative \
      -Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel:21.3.0.0-Final-java17 \
      -Dquarkus.container-image.push=true
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#split-long-commands

Comment: you don't need backslashes.

Comment: While that gets you nice, short lines in your config, the job-log will only print the first line of your multi-line construct. You will get some notice, that things have been omitted like `# collapsed multiline command`. Which obviously can be bad for troubleshooting or auditing.